# How to check a MongoDB record right after updating it?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

when I update a record in a MongoDb collection I immediately want to check whether or not all document field values equal `true`. For example, I have created a function that will update a record in my collection:

```
failureStatus.update(true);
```

It basically changes one of my documents field values to `true`.

Right after the `failureStatus.update()` function I would like to run another function like so:

```
FailureStatus.find({}, function (err, status) {
    if(status.failure === true && !err) {
      // Do something
    }
 });
```

This simply searches my collection and checks that documents contain a field value of true.

The only thing that is concerning me about this is JavaScript's asynchronous behaviour, what if my function runs before the DB has been updated?

Just wondering how other developers in JS & MongoDB community would handle this?

Thanks

Comment: use `FailureStatus.findOneAndUpdate()` with `{ 'new': true }` option which returns the updated record.

Answer (score 0):

How about placing the `FailureStatus.find` as a callback function of `failureStatus.update()`? That will ensure the timing.

Answer (score 0):

Generally promises would be used for something like this but you should become familiar with callbacks first, so I'd suggest you try something along the lines of the following.

```
updateStatus(true, ()=>{
    //then from here run your second check to see if all true
})


function updateStatus(status, callback){
  //update your record status to true 
  //then call your callback
  callback();
}
```